# Adding a name to the "from" field in SendGrid in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I want to add a name to my "from" field using the SendGrid API, but I do not know how to do this. I tried setting the "from" parameter in `sendgrid.send` to `Name <example@example.com>` but that didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the from parameter in a couple of ways:

```
var SendGrid = require('sendgrid').SendGrid;
var sendgrid = new SendGrid(user, key);
sendgrid.send({
  to: 'you@yourdomain.com',
  from: 'example@example.com',  // Note that we set the `from` parameter here
  fromname: 'Name', // We set the `fromname` parameter here
  subject: 'Hello World',
  text: 'My first email through SendGrid'
}, function(success, message) {
  if (!success) {
    console.log(message);
  }
});
```

or you can create an `Email` object and fill in the stuff on that:

```
var Email = require('sendgrid').Email;
var email = new Email({
  to: 'you@yourdomain.com',
  from: 'example@example.com',
  fromname: 'Name',
  subject: 'What was Wenger thinking sending Walcott on that early?',
  text: 'Did you see that ludicrous display last night?'
});

sendgrid.send(email, function() { 
  // ... 
});
```

You might want to take a few minutes and go over [the README document on the Github page](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs).  It has pretty detailed info on how to use the library and the various features it offers.

Comment: Thanks. I read that README and for some reason, I didn't see the `fromname` field in the docs while trying to find something about it. Next time I'll try Ctrl+F :)

Comment: what is user and key. I am thinking that is key is api key but what is user? that is username or any other

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. See @incinerator answer below.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Look https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903145/2803872 answer.

Comment: @Swift this doesn't work anymore. Can you please mention this in your answer?

Comment: here is the use case page in github https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/README.md#email-use-cases

Answer (score 128):

Updated example with the syntax used in the latest version of the [Sendgrid Node.js library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs).

```
sendgrid.send({
  to: 'you@yourdomain.com',
  from: {
      email: 'example@example.com',
      name: 'Sender Name'
  },
  subject: 'Hello World',
  text: 'My first email through SendGrid'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, same problem and I couldn't find the `name` field in the documentation, in-fact the docs aren't particularly easy to navigate around.

Comment: I agree. I have issued a [pull request](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/pull/645) trying to clarify this in the documentation somewhat, but to no avail so far.

Comment: Don't know if it was like this a few months ago, but this is documented in [github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#flexible-email-address-fields) now

Comment: Update: the PR mentioned above has finally been merged, almost a year later.

Comment: I found the docs here https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/use-cases/flexible-address-fields.md

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the Sendgrid API V3

Comment: This works. The accepted answer no longer works.

Comment: I think you need to set up a verified single sender for this to work.  https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth/senders

Answer (score 21):

Although the updated use cases don't include the `from` key

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/docs/use-cases/flexible-address-fields.md

This one worked for me

```
  to: 'user@userdomain.com',
  from: {
      name: 'Sender',
      email: 'me@mydomain.com',
  },
  subject: 'Hello World',
  html: `<html><p>Hello World</p></html>`
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: missing a comma ---- name: 'Sender', (fixed it)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the nodejs Helper library, use the following arguments:

```
from_email = new helper.Email("email@domain.com", "Email Name");
```

Answer (score 6):

from github on the node library you can use either of the methods below to have a send from email and name

```
from: {
   name: 'Name Here',
   email: 'email here'
}
```

or

```
from: "Cool Name <some@email.com>"
```

Answer (score 0):

For strapijs users, in plugins you can change like below

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  email: {
    config: {
      provider: 'sendgrid',
      providerOptions: {
        apiKey: env('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
      },
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: 'The Name You Want <myemail@protonmail.com>',
        defaultReplyTo: 'The Name You Want <myemail@protonmail.com>',
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```