# Adding a name to the “from” field in SendGrid in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

When the mail is received, in "from", I need to show the name of the person behalf of whom the mail is sent. I think what I need is the c# version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755545/adding-a-name-to-the-from-field-in-sendgrid-in-node-js) answer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a look to [MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class. You have an example on that page.

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane Clayton");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
message.Body = @"Using this feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

Be aware that SmtpClient, without params, takes the configuration from app.config / web.config. You can see the [mailSettings section](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/mailsettings-element-network-settings) for further configuration information

Comment: This assumes OP is using `SmtpClient` and not a SendGrid SDK.

Comment: And if it is just `SmtpClient`, this is a duplicate...

Comment: I would link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 instead. It is more detailed regarding this topic.